# ActiveRecord query to retrieve frequency depending on a condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

**Please, read everything**

Hello, I need to make some more or less complex calculations (at least for me), I've made a query with several joins to combine several tables and select some columns, but now I have to calculate the frequency of a field, this field is `deliver.status_id`, the problem is I have to do this calculation **taking into account only one `deliver_group.id`**, what do I mean by this? let's make an example:

If I have these selected columns...

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|  deliver.status_id  | deliver_group.id |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         11       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         13       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         13       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Then the `deliver.status_id` frequency would be `{1 => 2, 2 => 2, 3 => 2 4 => 1}`, but as I said I only have to take into account the one occurrence of `deliver_group.id`, this means the frequency would be `{1 => 1, 2 => 1, 3 => 1, 4 => 1}`, cause I have to "ignore" `deliver.status_id` when the `deliver_group.id` is repeated.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|  deliver.status_id  | deliver_group.id |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         11       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |   12 (ignored)   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |   12 (ignored)   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         13       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |   13 (ignored)   |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Another example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|  deliver.status_id  | deliver_group.id |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         7        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         8        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         9        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |    9 (ignored)   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         11       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |   11 (ignored)   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |   11 (ignored)   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |   12 (ignored)   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |   12 (ignored)   |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Would result in `{1 => 2, 2 => 1, 3 => 2, 4 => 1}`.

**By the way, I don't want to do this with ruby syntax, I mean, I know how to do this with a `Hash` and an iterator, blah, blah, blah, but I want to make the calculations completely with a query because the performance is key in this app**

I know the case where nothing is ignored is quite simple, `query.group('deliver.status_id').count`, but I'm lost with my actual case.

Comment: Is query.group('deliver_group.id, deliver.status_id').count('deliver.status_id') wat you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to group based on deliver.status_id and count (to get the frequency of each value in that column), but ignoring each row where deliver_group.id is repeated

Comment: How about throwing the mentioned result set into a temporary table called - ```temp_table(status_id, group_id)``` and run the query ```select status_id, MIN(group_id) from temp_table GROUP BY group_id;``` ?